# Pythonic idiom for constructing list from anonymous generator

Tags: python, generator, anonymous-function

I find the `yield`-based generators very useful for sequence operations that are too complex to use list comprehensions. Suppose I want to construct a list from a specialized generator. I can write it like:

```
def gen():
    for <whatever>:
        yield x

xs = list(gen())
```

A lot of the time, I only need to evaluate this generator once, so it doesn't really need a name. If Python had multi-line labmdas, I could use:

```
xs = list((lambda:
    for <whatever>:
        yield x)())
```

but Python doesn't have multi-line lambdas. Is there any other way to get something like this?

(note: please do not suggest using list comprehensions; I'm talking about cases where the logic of when to `yield` is more complex.)

Comment: you can write a generator expression `(x for x in range(5))` looks like a list comprehension but is a generator because it is inside `()`

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with your first approach or with using list comprehension either `[f(x) for x in container]` where `f(x)` implements the logic from `gen()`

Comment: Sounds like your only objection to a generator function is that it has a name.  Why is that? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

If the logic is too complex for a generator expression, you probably shouldn't be using a lambda. That's not the same as saying you can't.

Python lambdas can have as many newlines as you want. They just cannot contain *statements*, only an expression. You can use a `yield` *expression* (not a `yield` statement--you need the extra parentheses) in a lambda.

```
>>> list((lambda: (yield 1))())
[1]
```

Not that useful, is it? You can execute a list of yield expressions, using ... [a list display expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#list-displays)--`[]`. (Python guarantees the elements of displays are evaluated in order.)

```
>>> tuple((lambda:[
    (yield 1),
    (yield 2),
    (yield 3),
])())
(1, 2, 3)
```

Tuples work too. Look at that. Multiple "lines" (not statements). Still not that useful. You want to be able to loop. But the `for` statement is a statement. (Again, why not use a generator expresson? Those *are* expressions.) In practice, this is not that limiting, since lambdas can call functions which contain statements.

```
>>> def loop(itr, body):
    for x in itr:
        yield body(x)

        
>>> list(loop(range(9), lambda x: x*x))
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64]
```

That's how to make a for loop an expression without using a comprehension. But we want the loop inside the lambda.

```
>>> list((lambda:
      (yield from loop(range(9), lambda x:
               x*x))
      )())
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64]
```

Yep, `yield from` is also an expression. If you wrap it in parentheses. I think the nicely-indented `def`s are easier to read though. You can give it a short throwaway name, like `_f` or something.

---

The lambda calculus is Turing complete in its own right, capable of computing anything computable.

This means we technically don't even need the `loop` function. You can use recursion instead. (Though in Python, you'd eventually get a Stack Overflow ;) But how do you recurse on an anonymous function?

You use a "decorator" to give it a name.

```
>>> def recur(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(func, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

>>> tuple(recur(lambda r, n:[
    (yield n),
    (yield from r(r, n-1)) if n else 0]
     )(3))
(3, 2, 1, 0)
```

Of course, the "decorator" can be anonymous too.

```
>>> tuple((lambda f: lambda *a, **kw: f(f, *a, **kw))(lambda r, n:[
    (yield n),
    (yield from r(r, n-1)) if n else 0]
     )(3))
(3, 2, 1, 0)
```

I didn't write it that way in the first place because your eyes would glaze over from seeing too many lambdas. That's why you should use `def`!

If you're interested in just how far we can push lambdas like this, check out [Drython](https://github.com/gilch/drython), which has similar expression substitutions for every Python statement, and its successor project [Hebigo](https://github.com/gilch/hebigo), which mostly compiles to Python lambdas.

Answer (score 1):

Decorators don't *have* to return a function.

```
def genlist(g):
    return list(g())


@genlist
def xs():  # for <whatever>
    for x in range(3):
        yield x*x
    for x in range(3):
        yield x+x
    yield 42


print(xs)
```

---

```
[0, 1, 4, 0, 2, 4, 42]
```

In most cases where a rubyist wants a block in Python, it could be accomplished with a decorator like this.